# Qmake - doesn't copy file in linux

Tags: linux, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator, qmake

That code

```
defineTest(deployFiles) {
    win32 {
        to = $$shell_path($$3)
        for(entry,1){
            from = $$shell_path($$2/$$entry)
            QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cmd /c copy /y $$from $$to $$escape_expand(\n\t))
            PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$from
        }
        export(QMAKE_POST_LINK)
        export(PRE_TARGETDEPS)
    } else {
        to = $$shell_path($$3)
        for(entry,1){
            from = $$shell_path($$2/$$entry)
            QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(cp $$from $$to $$escape_expand(\n\t))
            PRE_TARGETDEPS += $$from
        }
        export(QMAKE_POST_LINK)
        export(PRE_TARGETDEPS)
    }
}
```

works only on Windows OS. Where `$$from` - file; `$$to` - directory.

And I unfortunately tried that:

```
QMAKE_POST_LINK += $$quote(xterm -e cp $$from $$to $$escape_expand(\n\t))
```

And `unix` instead `else`

If I put `message($$QMAKE_POST_LINK)` before export in linux block, in output I have message like that:

```
cp /home/user/QtProject/projects/Tools/qmldir /home/user/QtProject/qml/Tools/
cp /home/user/QtProject/projects/Tools/Tools.qml /home/user/QtProject/qml/Tools/
```

And output of `grep "qmldir" -C 5 <my_build_dir>/Makefile` (same as `grep "Tools\.qml" -C 5 <my_build_dir>/Makefile`) like that:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -o "$@" "$<"

####### Build rules

$(TARGET): /home/user/QtProject/projects/Tools/qmldir /home/user/QtProject/projects/Tools/Tools.qml $(OBJECTS)  


Makefile: ../../../projects/Tools/Tools.pro /home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf /home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
        /home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/common/shell-unix.conf \
        /home/user/Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/common/unix.conf \
```

Comment: 1. Why do you add `\n\t` inside of the quote? 2. Try adding `message($$from)` and `message($$to)` into the Linux block and re-run qmake to see if both variables contain the correct value. Does one of them contain a space?

Comment: 3. What are you trying to do with `for(entry,1)`? `1` is not a list, is it?

Comment: In linux block I write `message($$QMAKE_POST_LINK)` and output is correct, if I copy that output to terminal - that code work correct. `\n\t` for new line, without that in qmake_post_link commands in 1 line and 'cource can't work.
`1` - is list, and I told - that's work in windows.

Comment: What is the output? Please post it into the question and ping me. The shell you are using in your terminal (bash?) might behave differently than your default shell (dash?).

Comment: Post updated. cp is part of coreutils, isn't it? I don't use bash.

Comment: Kay looks good. Can you add the output of `grep "Tools\.qml" -C 5 <your_build_dir>/Makefile` and `grep "qmldir" -C 5 <your_build_dir>/Makefile`

Comment: @SimonWarta Post updated. What do you want to see in that?

Comment: Okay, your copy command from `QMAKE_POST_LINK` did not make it into the Makefile. Can you add the code where you call `deployFiles`? Do you have multiple `.pro` files or `.pri` project includes?

Comment: @SimonWarta single `.pri` and many `.pro` with diferent names, but what's the difference, if in Windows OS that's work perfect?

Comment: For every .pro file there is a `Makefile`. Are you sure you got the right one?

Comment: @SimonWarta Yeah, I'm sure, I have makefile for every `.pro` file.

Comment: Did you try adding `message($$QMAKE_POST_LINK)` after you call `deployFiles`? As you can see from the grep output, the `cp` command does not make it into the Makefile, so it must get lost somewhere.

Comment: After deploying `$$QMAKE_POST_LINK` is like in deploying. But I see one difference in Windows and Linux version: in Linux I have single `makefile` without lines `cp ...\qmldir` and `cp ...\.qml`, in Windows I have `makefile` without that lines, too, but there I have files `makefile.debug` and `makefile.release` with that lines.

Comment: That is why I ask if you are really really sure, you got the right Makefile ;) Build directories and release/debug structure works different on Linux and Windows

Comment: And what I must to do to solve that problem?

Comment: Check your build path in Qt Creator project settings. Take care of the Debug/Release setting. Remove all build directories in your projects folder and rebuild to see where the build is created. Find all Makefiles, e.g. using `find <your_build_dir> -name "Makefile"`

Comment: How I said, for every `.pro` I have one `Makefile` in every directories. And every `Makefile` without lines for copy `qmldir` and `.qml` files.

Comment: How I said, please add the code where you call `defineTest`. Your code works for me in this file https://gist.github.com/webmaster128/66d495b4b1ff7962e770. The Quoting is not done properly but at least there are commands in the Makefile

Comment: @SimonWarta That [project](https://github.com/razieru/app_sandbox) work in Windows but not in Linux.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project which does not work is of [TEMPLATE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#template) type "aux", which is used when no compiler and no linker is involved. Thus the link command is empty.

Looks like `QMAKE_POST_LINK` is written only if there is a link command.

Makefile from `app_sandbox.pro` (TEMPLATE = app):

```
####### Build rules

$(TARGET):  $(OBJECTS)  
    @test -d ../../bin/ || mkdir -p ../../bin/
    $(LINK) $(LFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS) $(OBJCOMP) $(LIBS)

Makefile: ../../projects/app_sandbox/app_sandbox.pro ../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf ../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
```

Makefile from `Controls.pro` (TEMPLATE = aux):

```
####### Build rules

$(TARGET): /home/simon/nobackup/app_sandbox/projects/Design/Controls/qmldir /home/simon/nobackup/app_sandbox/projects/Design/Controls/TreeView.qml $(OBJECTS)  


Makefile: ../../../projects/Design/Controls/Controls.pro ../../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++/qmake.conf ../../../../Qt/5.4/gcc_64/mkspecs/features/spec_pre.prf \
```

As you can see, both specify dependencies for the target (after `$(TARGET):`) but there is no link command in the seconds Makefile.

Comment: But in [TEMPLATE](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#template) type "aux" not "Windows only", why that works only in Windows? I don't understand. You mean, I can't create project like in Windows if I use "aux" type? Or I must somewere write link command?

Comment: I have no clue why I does work on Windows. Might be some qmake internal reason. You need to find another way to write copy commands into the aux template.